# Karate scenerio creation for testing error message returned in JSON format

Tags: karate

I have one get operation which returns below format while fetching invalid data

```
{
    "exchangeReturnCod": "ERROR",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "XXX",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "source": "Application with id APPLICATIONNOTEXIST doesn't exist.",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to match this error message in feature file. I have used below syntaxes but none is working.

And match response.feedbacks errors **{source:"Application with id APPLICATIONNOTEXIST doesn't exist."}**

Could you please guide what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
* def expected = {source:"Application with id APPLICATIONNOTEXIST doesn't exist."}
* match $response.errors[*].source contains expected.source
```

Since your response returns an array of `errors` this will validate atleast one error should have the expected source.